# When using Dropbox APIs I get media_info=NOT_SET for images even if they are actually visible from web interface

Tags: python, image, metadata, dropbox-api

I'm using Python APIs.

When I try getting metadata for one JPG file from a folder, for example using

`dbx.files_get_metadata("path/to/image.jpg")`

I see the tag `media_info=NOT_SET`. On the other hand, if I go to the browser and check the file, in the toolbar I see this:

[image: metadata image]

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/media-info-NOT-SET-even-if-they-are-actually-visible-from-web/td-p/713919 ]